# Basic summation of conditional probabilities question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I read on Bishop Chap8 P 374 that:

sum(P(b|c)P(c|a)) = P(b|a) where the sum is over c.

Can you prove that?

Comment: No. Does Bishop have a proof?

Comment: no he just uses that in one of his computations http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/prml/pdf/Bishop-PRML-sample.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only true if $p(b\mid a, c) = p(b \mid c)$ i.e. if $a,b$ are conditionally independent given $c$. Bishop states that this is assumed.

Compute
\begin{align}
p(a, b) &= \sum p(a, b, c) = \sum p(b\mid a, c)p(a, c) \\
&= \sum p(b \mid c)p(c \mid 
a)p(a) = p(a) \sum p(b\mid c) p(c \mid a).
\end{align}

Since $p(a, b)/p(a) = p(b\mid a)$ the equality holds: $\sum p(b\mid c) p(c \mid a) = p(b\mid a)$.